# Designing an API for service operations with closely related parameters

Tags: c#, design, wcf, api-design

I'm having trouble deciding how to design this service API.

```
public class GetCurrentValuesRequest
{
    public int ReferenceID { get; set; }
    public int[] FilterIDs { get; set; }
}

public class GetDefaultValuesRequest
{
    public int[] FilterIDs { get; set; }
}

public class GetValuesAsOfDateRequest
{
    public int ReferenceID { get; set; }
    public int[] FilterIDs { get; set; }
    public DateTime AsOf { get; set; }
}

public class GetValuesAsOfChangeSetRequest
{
    public int ReferenceID { get; set; }
    public int[] FilterIDs { get; set; }
    public long ChangeSetIDs { get; set; }
}

public class GetProposedValuesRequest
{
    public int ReferenceID { get; set; }
    public int[] FilterIDs { get; set; }
    public long ApprovalKey { get; set; }
}

public class GetValuesIfModifiedRequest
{
    public int ReferenceID { get; set; }
    public int[] FilterIDs { get; set; }
    public DateTime Since { get; set; }
}

public class GetValuesResponse
{
    public string[] Results { get; set; }
}

public class GetValuesIfModifiedResponse
{
    public string[] Results { get; set; }
    public bool IsModified { get; set; }
}

public interface IService
{
    GetValuesResponse GetValues(GetCurrentValuesRequest request);

    GetValuesResponse GetValues(GetDefaultValuesRequest request);

    GetValuesResponse GetValues(GetValuesAsOfDateRequest request);

    GetValuesResponse GetValues(GetValuesAsOfChangeSetRequest request);

    GetValuesResponse GetValues(GetProposedValuesRequest request);

    GetValuesIfModifiedResponse GetValuesIfModified(GetValuesIfModifiedRequest request);
}
```

I've thought about changing it to have make the `IfModified` request / response subclasses of the simple `GetValues` request response and only including one `GetValues` call. The server would return a different response depending on the input request, but that requires user to call `IService` this:

```
var response = (GetValuesIfModifiedResponse)serviceClient.GetValues(new GetValuesIfModifiedRequest() { ... });
```

I've also thought about placing `IsModified` in the simple `GetValuesResponse`, and only populating it if a `GetValuesIfModifiedRequest` is passed into it. But that seems a bit strange to include it in a result from a method which does not actually do anything with it. Also, it might throw of a user if they see it and expect to be able to use it in their code. `bool? IsModified` is better, but I'm not entirely sold on it just yet.

Any suggestions for how to best design this API?

Comment: What's wrong with simply setting `IsModified` to `false` if the response is not modified?  I don't see a good reason to provide two different responses.

Comment: Because `IsModified == false` may not be accurate. In fact the use case for this property is `if (response.IsModified) { refreshCache(); }` so if the service is not called correctly, the cache would never get refreshed.

Comment: What does "called correctly" mean?  Does the service need to return a tri-state value instead of a boolean one?

Comment: If "AsOf" is requested, the server goes through a few extra checks before returning, and if `IsModified == false` then the `Results` array is empty. So `IsModified` provides extra information about the state of the system. I'd rather have `IsModified == null` indicate that no such checks were made.

Comment: OK.  So the three states are Modified, Unmodified, NotChecked?

Comment: Correct. Are you suggesting an `enum`? I hadn't considered it but it makes sense.

Comment: It just seems like some of this return state information is kind of hidden, and an Enum would be much more declarative and self-explanatory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, your sole request object should look something like this:

```
public class GetValuesRequest
{
    public int[] FilterIDs { get; set; }
    public DateTime SearchDate { get; set; }
    public SearchType SearchType { get; set; }
}

public enum SearchType
{
    AsOf,
    Since
}
```

You can tweak this to your taste, but the point is that there is only one search date submitted, and the enum provides a switch mechanism between past and future.

You can then return an object thusly:

```
public class GetValuesResponse
{
    public string[] Results { get; set; }
    public CacheState CacheResult { get; set; }
}

public enum CacheState
{
    Modified,
    Unmodified,
    NotChecked
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply, but I don't really like relying on users to set flags (`AsOf`) in order to use the request correctly. It also means I have to account for *every* combination of parameters a user might throw into the request (my actual class has many more methods of querying data, many of which are not compatible with each other).

Comment: The only thing I would change about your updated example is that the service should return only one type with a cache status.  Returning two types complicates things for the caller.

Comment: Agreed. Which is why I like your `CacheState` enum (+1). But when I think of trying to express all the logic of every variety of request in a single request class, it makes me cringe. I think it's just asking for malformed or incomplete requests.

Comment: So don't.  I don't mind that each request type is declared with it's own class.  But return values are not polymorphic like parameters are, so return a single type instead of the two types that you're proposing, unless there's some compelling reason why the user must accept a different return type for "If Modified" requests.

Comment: That's what I'm going with. Thanks for helping me reason my way through it.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like you're trying to create a dynamic query over http. Have you looked at OData? Since you're using WCF, there is built-in support as of 4.0 I believe for implementing OData called [WCF Data Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd728286.aspx), all you have to do is return IQueryable from your service methods. For convenience, you can create helper queries on your client library that wraps around the OData queries. So your service interface would now look like

```
public interface IService
{
    IQueryable<Values> GetValues();
}
```

And your client library would contain helper functions that call the service.

```
public class ServiceClient
{
   //Injected or initialized see docs under previous link on accessing a service
   private IService _service
   public IEnumerable<Values>GetFilteredValues(int[] filterIds)
   {
      //get the values matching passed in Ids.
      return from _service.GetValues().Where(v => filterIds.Contains(v.Id));
   }

   public IEnumerable<Values>GetFilteredValuesAsOf(int[] filterIds, DateTime asOf)
   {
      //get the values matching passed in Ids and created since the asOf date
      return from _service.GetValues().
             Where(v => filterIds.Contains(v.Id) && v.CreatedOn > asOf);
   }

}
```

The beauty of this is that the query happens server side. If it is backed by a Database, the database handles it.

Comment: The op mentioned there was some other logic that occurs, if it can be expressed using linq syntax then this is the right approach.

Comment: I've considered that, but at the moment that's too big of a change for my service to support.

Comment: Also the `IQueryable` cannot be evaluated by the database because it would involve features not supported by my ORM (EF 4, but I might be able to do it when I upgrade to EF 5)